# To show that the function is not holomorphic at origin but satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equation

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $$ f(z) = \left\{ \begin{align}
&e^{-\frac{1}{z^4}}  &\hspace{1mm} \mbox{if} \hspace{1mm} z \neq 0 \\ 
&0  &\hspace{1mm} \mbox{if} \hspace{1mm} z = 0 \\ 
\end{align} \right. $$

I have to show that this function satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equation at $z=0$, but is not holomorphic.

I have been able to prove that it satisfies Cauchy-Riemann. But I am struggling with proving that it is not holomorphic at $z=0$.

My attempt:

Let $z=x+iy$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Then 
$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}.$$
So
$$\frac{1}{z^4}=\frac{x^4+y^4-6x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^4}+i\frac{4xy^3-4x^3y}{(x^2+y^2)^4}.$$

Then 
$$e^{-\frac{1}{z^4}}=e^{-\frac{x^4+y^4-6x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^4}}\left(\cos\left(\frac{4xy^3-4x^3y}{(x^2+y^2)^4} \right)-i \sin\left(\frac{4xy^3-4x^3y}{(x^2+y^2)^4} \right)\right)$$

My idea is the following:

> If we can show that $f$ is not continuous at $z=0$, then it will follow automatically that $f$ is not holomorphic.

To show that $f$ is not continuous, I am trying to show that $f$ has different limits as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ along different paths. I have tried the paths  $y=x$, $y=-x$, $y=x^2$. But all these paths give the limit to be $0$, which is the value of $f$ at $z=0$.

(1) Is my idea wrong and the function is continuous at $z=0$?

(2) If $f$ is not continuous, which path can be used to prove it?

Comment: If it were holomorphic it would have a power-series expansion around zero. What can you say about the coefficients?

Comment: @uniquesolution I suppose that the OP meant to say that it is not *differentiable* at the origin.

Comment: @Jose Carlos Santos But it is differentiable at the origin. In fact, it is differentiable infinitely many times at the origin, but it is not holmorphic there. (holomorphic=analytic). I suppose the OP meant to say exactly what (s)he said.

Comment: @uniquesolution No, it is not differentiable at the origin. It is not even continuous there.

Comment: Yes you are right -- I assumed - mistakenly - that $z$ is real.

Comment: @uniquesolution It's not differintiable, neither as a complex function nor real. And that's important. If a function is differentiable as a real function and fulfills the CR equation it would be differentiable as an complex function (that is holomorphic).

Comment: @skyking Is it your claim that as a real valued function the given function is not differentiable at the origin? If my memory does not betray me, this is a classical example of a function (real valued) having all derivatives at the origin (equal to zero!) but not real-analytic there.

Comment: @uniquesolution I meant considered as a function $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$, that is the function $\phi(x,y) = (\Re f(x+iy), \Im f(x+iy))$. It's only the partial derivates that vanish at $(0,0)$ - there already exists example of partially derivable functions that are not differentiable.

Comment: @skyking - This is not the correct context. What is $(x,y)^4$ for an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @uniquesolution I don't know what you mean. Perhaps you misunderstood. The function $\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ is **not** defined just by just substituting in the formula. There is no reason to ask what element $(x,y)^4$ is. It's formed using the template above. Or put it another way we use the language of the CR equations which uses two functions $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ - if both of these are differentiable and fulfil the CR equations then the function $f(x+iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ is holomorphic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $f$ is not even continuous at $0$. If $z=\rho\left(\cos\left(\frac\pi8\right)+\sin\left(\frac\pi8\right)i\right)$ with $\rho>0$, then $z^4=\rho^4i$ and therefore$$\bigl|f(z)\bigr|=\left\lvert\exp\left(-\frac1{z^4}\right)\right\rvert=\left\lvert\exp\left(\frac i{\rho^4}\right)\right\rvert=1.$$So, $f(z)$ doesn't even get near $0$ when $z$ belongs to the ray with origin at $0$ and passing through $\cos\left(\frac\pi8\right)+\sin\left(\frac\pi8\right)i$.